# How can I customise colors in the highlight section that is different from the text colors?

Tags: tinymce, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

[Image to the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2w4J.jpg)

How to give custom colors for highlights different from text colors.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#textcoloroptions) states that the color_map setting sets both of them.

Additionally looking at the source code you can confirm that this is not currently possible as both swatches get the colors from the same function.

See
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/themes/silver/main/ts/ui/core/color/ColorSwatch.ts#L135